# Applying function to all strings in TextView

Tags: java, android, arabic

I have a function to connect disconnected arabic alphabets (this problem is only appearing in those phones which do not have arabic installed).

I can use this function successfully for the `TextView` applying it this way:

```
text.setText(ArabicReshaper.shape(whateverstring));
```

The problem is I have too many strings in my application. I would like to know if there is any  other way I can apply Shaper function to all the `TextViews` and `Buttons` in one go rather than doing it manually one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `TextView` class, override `setText` method and use it everywhere in your app instead of regular `TextView`

Comment: I extended the `TextView` and it works great if I use the example provided by others. However, I want to use the function only if the locale is set to arabic.

Comment: You can add the check for Locale in your custom `setText`. And if you need to update all text views when locale changes to arabic - you might probably have separate string file for arabic locale, so all active TextViews will be recreated automatically

Answer (score 0):

Ex.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    private CharSequence mText;

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(ArabicReshaper.shape(text), type);
    }


}
```

Comment: This works great! The only thing is that if I do this: `public void setText(String text) {
   super.setText(getString(text));
  }
 
  private String getString(String str) {
   ArabicShaping.shape(str);
   return str;
  }` it doesn't work. But if I do it the way you did, it works. Any reason why? The reason why I'm doing it this way is because I want to first get the locale. If the locale is set to Arabic, only then would I want to apply this function.